# Using find method to search values

Tags: vba, excel

When the code executes this line Set r = tbl.Find(what:=mx) and if cell contains repeated zeros or any number it returns same location repeatedly. For example if I have repeated zeros to search for: It gives me result as V1B, V1B, V1B instead of returning V1B, V2B and V2C. I think it does only if the values are repeated. How to modify this code?

```
  V1   V2   V3
```

A    1       5     9

B    0       0     0

C    7       8     4

Sub Finder() 
    Dim tabl As Range, headr As Range, mx As Double
    Dim r As Range, colr As Range
    Dim p As Long

```
With Sheet1

    For p = 1 To 9
        Set tbl =.Range("B3:D5")
        Set headr =.Range("B2:D2")
        Set colr =.Range("A3:A5")
        mx =.Cells(6 + p, 3)
        Set r = tbl.Find(what:=mx)
        v = Intersect(headr, r.EntireColumn).Value
        v = v & " " & Intersect(colr, r.EntireRow).Value
        .Cells(6 + p, 2) = v
    Next p
End with
```

End Sub

Comment: Have a look at the .FindNext method - you'll have to stop it from infinitely looping through your range!

Comment: @Citizenkong: I was trying .FindNext method, do you know how to use in this code?

Comment: the trick is that you need to stop `Find`ing when you reach the starting address again, or if you're changing things as you go, until `Find` returns `Nothing`.

Comment: [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started

Comment: @Siddharth thanks..I will check out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical way to find all the zeros in a block of cells *(it will ignore blanks!)*

```
Sub ZeroFinder()
    Dim Block As Range, Zero As Long, _
        r As Range, msg As String, st As String
    Set Block = Range("D6:O32")
    Zero = 0
    Set r = Block.Find(What:=Zero, after:=Block(1))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "no zeros"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    msg = r.Address(0, 0)
    st = msg
    Do Until r Is Nothing
        Set r = Block.FindNext(after:=r)
        If r.Address(0, 0) = st Then Exit Do
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Address(0, 0)
    Loop
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: What was happening in the first code is when the code executes this line Set r = tbl.Find(what:=mx) and if cell contains repeated zeros or 1's. For example if A1 contains 0, b1 contains 0 and c1 contains 0. It gives me result as A1, A1, A1 instead of A1, B1 and C1. I think it does only if the value is either 1 or 0.